# Why does a stranger lend Akira pants?

Tags: eden-of-the-east

During the first episode, we see Akira running down the street without pants. Then he asks a bystander, and the guy just lends his pants to Akira. Is this related to some cultural reference, or is it never explained and is a strange plot element even to Westerners?

Comment: In Anime strangers tend to be far kinder people and less likely to think your insane if you asked them for their pants as one would do in real life (if not get turned into the nearest police station/crazy house), and i may be totally mistaken in thinking that this is just apart of Japanese culture, being kind to strangers.

Comment: However Saki, as a Japanese, was shocked that the guy actually lend Akira pants.

Comment: And it didn't make much sense for the woman police officer to demand to see his johnny, be blushed by it, and just let him go. Does his johnny have Geass or something?

Answer (score 2):

It's never explained but I imagine that Akira transferred him some large amount of money from his phone. The man is clearly elated at whatever Akira offered him.